# Inserting module with controller in function AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, iife

why if I insert angular module with controller into function, angularjs stop working?

```
(function() {
      var app = angular.module("app", []);

      app.controller("c1", function($scope){

          $scope.name = "Hello World!";

      });  
 });
```

Comment: What does stop working mean? What errors show up?

Comment: no error in the console

Comment: Your function is not being called!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neglected the code of the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (parenthesis at the end: `()` ).

Below there is a snippet with your sample corrected.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);

  app.controller("c1", function($scope){

  $scope.name = "Hello World!";

  });  
})(); //<< -- here!! See the closing ()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="c1">
{{name}}
</div>
```

You can read more about IIFE here:

- [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression